# Interface 'Psr\Log\LoggerInterface' not found [Google Calendar Api]

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client

I just finished migrate my server and

I get below error when trying to create event using Google Calendar Api , what might be the problem ?

> ```
> Fatal error: Interface 'Psr\Log\LoggerInterface' not found in /var/www/html/elois.fr/www/vendors/google-api-php-client/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php
> ```

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

I resolve my problem, in my *google-api-phpclient>vendor>psr* it missing the folder **log**